# Flutter: inkwell routing different pages from list index

Tags: flutter, flutter-routes

I want to route each index to a different page but I can not do this please help me :(

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      PageRouteBuilder(
                        pageBuilder: (context, a,b,) => DetailPage(
                          planetInfo: planets[index],

                        ),

                      ),
                    );
                  },
```

Comment: Could you add more details about your code? What is coming before this Inkwell?

Comment: https://github.com/erdemsoftwarengineer/world17_app

Comment: Page not found .